# Use value from AsyncStorage for VideoThumbnails.getThumbnailAsync

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to use the expo-video-thumbnails package to generate a thumbnail from a video uri. The video uri is retrieved from async-storage. I get the following error

> Argument of an incompatible class: class java.util.HashMap cannot be
> passed as an argument to parameter expecting class java.lang.String.

If I use a static video uri, it works fine. I can't seem to get this to work with the value from AsyncStorage. Here's my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Image } from 'react-native';

import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import * as VideoThumbnails from 'expo-video-thumbnails';


export default function ThumbnailsScreen() {


  // video uri
  const [videoUri, setVideoUri] = React.useState({});
  const getData = async () => {
      try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@lastRecordedVideo')
      if(value !== null) {
        setVideoUri(value)
      }
      } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
  }
  getData();

  // thumbnails
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const generateThumbnail = async () => {
    try {
      const { uri } = await VideoThumbnails.getThumbnailAsync(
        videoUri,
        {
          time: 1000,
        }
      );
      setImage(uri);
    } catch (e) {
      console.warn(e);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => { generateThumbnail(); }, [])

  return (
    <View>
    {image && <Image source={{ uri: image }} /> }
    </View>
  )

}
```

Comment: Can you share code snippet on how you're saving URI in Async Storage?

Comment: `const storeData = async (key, value) => {
    try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value)
    } catch (e) {
        // saving error
    }
  }

const data = await camera.recordAsync({
          maxDuration:maxDuration,
        })

storeData('@lastRecordedVideo', data.uri);`

Comment: If I hardcore the static value instead of the videoUri variable, it works just fine.

Comment: Try to stringify ´data.uri` as ´data.uri.toString()´